# Javascript - How to create an array using a orignal array and a variable to determine how many time a the value of an array can go into the variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create an Array stating the number of times the approved quantity goes into the original quantity (vqty) and the approved qty associated with it (aqty). The original quantity decreases after each iteration.

For example -
var ApprovedQty = [680,120,450,40];
var OriginalQty = 10000;

var NewArray = [(vqty:aqty),(vqty:aqty),(vqty:aqty),(vqty:aqty)]

use some sort of for loop to generate the NewArray by sorting the original array in descending order and dividing original qty by the value in the array.

ideally its 10000/680 = 14.07 so the first value in NewArray is (14:680). Then Original qty becomes 10000 - (680x14) = 480

then 480 / 450 = 1.06 so the second value in NewArray is (1:450). Then original qty becomes 480 - (450 x1) = 30

then 30 / 120 = .25 ..since 120 is not the last available value in the orginal array, the value in the new array is (0:120) and the original qty stays 30

then 30/40 = .75..since 40 is the last value in the array, the value in the new array is (1:40)

so the newarray is [(14:680),(1:450),(0:120),(1:40)]

Comment: 40 doesn't go into 30?  How is that final element 1?

Comment: the goal is to split the 10,000 across the differnet sizes and since 40 is the lowest value you have to create a batch for that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted parts by using a closure which is a function which returns a function and keeps variable `total`.

The code checks if the the last index is reached and takes `ceil` as method, otherwise `floor` and calls it later with the division by the value of the (previously sorted) array.

Then `total` gets the rest and `parts` is returned as result.

```js
const
    getParts = total => (value, i, { length }) => {
        const
            method = i + 1 === length ? 'ceil' : 'floor',
            parts = Math[method](total / value);

        total %= value;
        return parts;
    },
    values = [680, 450, 120, 40],
    result = values.map(getParts(10000));

console.log(...result);
```